# CXF SOAP Client with NTLM to SharePoint

Tags: java, sharepoint, soap, cxf, ntlm

I am writing a SOAP client using CXF Framework (version: 2.7.8) for SharePoint 2007.  I have followed the online documentation for adding NTLM support [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/Asynchronous+Client+HTTP+Transport).  I have the client working and tracing the HTTP session shows that NTLM credentials are being sent, however, I am still receiving a 401 Unauthorized response.

Code:

```
Lists listService = new Lists();
ListsSoap port = listService.getListsSoap();

BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
bp.getRequestContext().put("use.async.http.conduit", Boolean.TRUE);
Credentials creds = new NTCredentials(USER, PASS, "", DOMAIN);
bp.getRequestContext().put(Credentials.class.getName(), creds);

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(proxy);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
httpClientPolicy.setAutoRedirect(true);
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

// Build request and execute
```

Interestingly, I wrote a similar client using HTTP PUT for WebDAV to upload documents using Apache HTTPClient library, and was able to successfully authenticate using NTLM.  Also, I was able to use SOAPUI to invoke the same Lists web service I am trying to build the Java client for and it successfully authenticated using NTLM as well.

I'm assuming the implementation of NTLM is different between CXF and HTTPClient.  Any thoughts on what is wrong with my CXF implementation?  Or how I can get it  to mirror the HTTPClient implementation?

Answer (score 5):

Please try this way!

```
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit)client.getConduit();
AsyncHTTPConduit conduit = (AsyncHTTPConduit)http;
DefaultHttpAsyncClient defaultHttpAsyncClient;
defaultHttpAsyncClient = conduit.getHttpAsyncClient();
defaultHttpAsyncClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials( AuthScope.ANY,
 new NTCredentials( USER,PWD, "", DOM ) );
conduit.getClient().setAllowChunking( false );
conduit.getClient().setAutoRedirect( true );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When I try your suggestion I get: `org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.transport.http.asyncclient.AsyncHTTPConduit`.  I am retrieving my Client using `ClientProxy.getClient(proxy)`.  Ideas?

Comment: In order to use org.apache.cxf.transport.http.asyncclient.AsyncHTTPConduit instread of org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit we need to change CXF trannsport to cxf-rt-transports-http-hc-x.x.x.jar

Answer (score 1):

@lamarvannoy, I also got this error. But I found another way. You don't need to cast HTTPConduit to AsyncHTTPConduit. Let's try this stuff:

```
public class Test {

    static final String kuser = "yourDomain\\username";
    static final String kpass = "yourPassword";

    static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            System.err.println("Feeding username and password for " + getRequestingScheme());
            return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
        Lists listService = new Lists();
        ListsSoap port = listService.getListsSoap();

        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
        httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
        http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

        String listName = "S030_main";
        String rowLimit = "150";
        ArrayList<String> listColumnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        listColumnNames.add("Title");     
        Test.displaySharePointList(port, listName, listColumnNames, rowLimit);       
    }
}
```

You may find the implementation of displaySharePointList() method in this post: http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-java-tutorial/

I hope this will safe your and others time.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
AsyncHTTPConduit conduit = (AsyncHTTPConduit)client.getConduit();
AuthorizationPolicy authorization = conduit.getAuthorization();
authorization.setUserName("domain\\username");
authorization.setPassword("password");
```

Actually this works for both NTLM and Basic

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had to do to get mine to work:

```
// Include a version of WSDL in class path, make URL point to that
URL url = MyClient.class.getResource("previouslydownloaded.wsdl");

MyCxFService ws = new MyCxFService(url);
MyCxfClient client = ws.getMyCxfServicePort(); 

BindingProvider prov = ((BindingProvider) client);
Binding binding = prov.getBinding();

// Set Username and Password
if ((this.user != null) && (!this.user.isEmpty())) {
  prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, this.user);
  prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, this.passwd);
}

// Get address from config file to get rid error caused by using wsdl file:
// Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
//   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit.createConnection(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:104)
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, this.portAddress);
```

Hope that might help someone.