# How to invoke the .Net Based webservice from a java client with NTLM authentication

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, ntlm

I want to invoke the .NET Based webservice from a java client code. I generated JAX-WS stubs using wsimport tool.

This is how credentials are being created in .NET client-

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, "domain");
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = credential ;
```

How do we do it similarly in Java Client? I searched a lot and found some posts suggesting to do NTLM authentication but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

NTLM authentication is not supported by JAX-WS but you still have a couple alternatives

**Alternative 1:**
Create your own authenticator and set it as default, it will be used for all of you HTTP communications.
Use this alternative only if the communication is server2server, since it's not optimal to use multiple multiple user accounts. 
You can see the code of how to implement it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html

**Alternative 2:**
Another alternative is to use Axis2, which uses the HTTPClient behind the scene. It will select the best authentication method suited for your scenario.
[axis2 client NTLM authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865539/axis2-client-ntlm-authentication)

**Note:** Axis2 has issues with some versions of  NTLM and some people is recomending to move to CFX [CXF SOAP Client with NTLM to SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739141/cxf-soap-client-with-ntlm-to-sharepoint)

These alternative require you to include new libraries in your code, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Pablo for your response. I tried 2nd alternative with below code -   ServiceClass serviceClass = new ServiceClass();
  PortInterface client = serviceClass.getPort(PortInterface.class);
  
  BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) client;
  bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("use.async.http.conduit", Boolean.TRUE);
  Credentials creds = new NTCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD, "", DOMAIN);
  bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(Credentials.class.getName(), creds);  But it throws - PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied".

Comment: Tried other code snippets too from your link but not able to proceed. Do you have any other implementation for same. Also wsdl uses below tag for security, I still need to follow NTLM auth, right? - <http:NegotiateAuthentication xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http"/>

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? Did you test with CFX?

Comment: With CFX - I am getting this exception - org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.

Comment: I had changed code little but still same PolicyException. I posted code snippet here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630212/cxf-throws-none-of-the-policy-alternatives-can-be-satisfied